# Debounced function runs multiple times in some scenario

Tags: javascript, marionette

I have a view which looks like:

```
var ListItemButtonView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'button',
    className: 'listItem-button',

    events: {
        'click': '_onClick',
        'dblclick': '_onClick'
    },

    //  Debounced to defend against accidental/spam clicking.
    _onClick: _.debounce(function () {
        if (!this.$el.hasClass('disabled')) {
            this._doOnClick();
        }

        //  Don't allow click to bubble up to the list item and cause a selection.
        return false;
    }, 100, true),

    _doOnClick: function(){
        this.model.destroy();
        console.log('Do on click has ran');
    }
});
```

This code works fine for me locally and I have had no issues with it. In production, I am seeing an error which indicates that `_doOnClick` is running more than once. This does not make sense to me because the view is removed when its model is destroyed. A second model.destroy command should not be possible. Additionally, I guard the _onClick event by debouncing the function with immediate set to true. From underscore's documentation, http://underscorejs.org/#debounce, it says:

> "Pass true for the immediate parameter to cause debounce to trigger
>   the function on the leading instead of the trailing edge of the wait
>   interval. Useful in circumstances like preventing accidental
>   double-clicks on a "submit" button from firing a second time."

Is there anything incorrect about my implementation which could result in some users managing to run _doOnClick multiple times?

EDIT:

My only hunch so far is that, if the user's machine is running especially slow, 100ms might not be a long enough delay for the view to be cleaned up. I've increased the delay and will see if that resolves anything.

Comment: Did increasing the delay help?

Comment: It did! Sorry, I forgot about this question.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the delay to 1s made the issue go away. There's probably a more elegant solution out there, though.

Here's what my code looks like now. Note that I changed the structure a bit because defining the function as debounced at the class-declaration level rather than upon instantiation was resulting in the timer being shared between all instances of the view rather than giving a separate timer to each instance.

```
var ListItemButtonView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'button',
    className: 'listItem-button',

    events: {
        'click': '_onClick',
        'dblclick': '_onDblClick'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        //  Debounced to defend against accidental/spam clicking. Bound in initialize because
        //  the debounce timer will be shared between all ListItemButtonViews if bound before initialize.
        this._debounceOnClickAction = _.debounce(this._doOnClickAction.bind(this), 1000, true);
    },

    _onClick: function () {
        this._debounceOnClickAction();
        //  Don't allow click to bubble up since handling click at this level.
        return false;
    },

    _onDblClick: function () {
        this._debounceOnClickAction();
        //  Don't allow dblClick to bubble up since handling click at this level.
        return false;
    },

    _debounceOnClickAction: null,

    _doOnClickAction: function() {
        if (!this.$el.hasClass('disabled')) {
            this.doOnClickAction();
        }
    }
});
```